# Finding largest elements in array efficiently

Tags: java, comparison

I have a program that finds the two largest elements of an Array. I have to look at the number of comparisons between elements of the Array to determine efficiency (not big-O) I have determined the worst-case is 2n-3 comparisons (assuming the first two elements are the largest) Here is the function.

```
Integer[] A = {11,22,8,7,5,6,7,8,1,9};
    int largest = 0;
    int secondLargest = 0;
    int count = 1;
    if (A[0] < A[1]){
        largest = A[1];
        secondLargest = A[0];
    } else {
        largest = A[0];
        secondLargest = A[1];
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < A.length; i++){
        count++;
        if (A[i] > largest) {

            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = A[i];
        } else {
            count++;
            if (A[i] > secondLargest) { 
                secondLargest = A[i];
            }
        }
    }
System.out.println("Largest:" + largest + " Second:" + secondLargest + " count:" + count);
```

I use count to determine the number of comparisons. 
Is there any way to reduce the number of worst case comparisons within this function? I can't figure out how to make this function better.

Comment: Just pre-sort the array and, technically, you will know its to biggest elements  in a constant time!

Comment: Your algorithm appears optimal for the worst case number of operations.

Comment: By the way, algorithms which find the smallest (or largest) *n* elements in an array are called [partial sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2n - 3` (via `1 + 2(n-2)`) as a worst case is about as good as you can get: you have to look at all `n` values, and for each of those you have to check against the `2` largest values in the worst case scenario.

You can gain some efficiency if you swap the checks:

```
if ( A[i] > secondLargest )
{
   if ( A[i] > largest )
     secondLargest = largest,
     largest = A[i];
   else
     secondLargest = A[i];
}
```

because if a value is not higher than secondLargest, it won't be larger than the largest. In a best case scenario (descending sorted list), this increases the efficiency to `n - 3`, whereas your algorithm also has `2n - 3` here.

However, the worst case scenario (an ascending sorted list) will still be the same.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what algorithm you pick you will be able to come up with scenario where each element has to be compared to the largest and second largest.

However in the more common randomly distributed case you could avoid a lot of comparisons by comparing to the second largest value first. Most elements will be less than the second largest value and will avoid the second comparison.

```
if (value > secondLargest) {
    secondLargest = value;
    if (secondLargest > largest) {
        int temp = largest;
        largest = secondLargest;
        secondLargest = temp;
    }
}
```

Or better (IMO):

```
int[] largest = new int[2];
for (int value: A) {
    if (value > largest[1]) {
        largest[1] = value;
        Arrays.sort(largest); 
    }
}
```

Note that for small arrays `Arrays.sort` just does a simple compare and swap.